# KEYCLOAK SPI: Keycloak Provider is null when trying to get data from db

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I have an issue on creating an spi to extend keycloak and create a new entity.
I followed the zonaut example(https://github.com/zonaut/keycloak-extensions/tree/master/provider-domain), and it works to add a new entity.

But when I try to get or save entities from the keycloak database using a keycloak provider as the keycloak example I have an issue. The provider is null.
For this case I followed the keycloak example:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/domain-extension

Here is my repo if you want to look at the source code:
https://github.com/Naouf3l/kc-extension

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code on the error message you receive and example code of the code that is not working. To help you one shouldn't have to go through your whole code repo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.